# Ошибка при десериализации XML файла в C#

Tags: c#, xml

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой ошибкой при десериализации XML файла:
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

Мой C# код, который читает файл:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("errors"), XmlType("errors")]
public class Errors
{
    [XmlType("error")]
    public class Error
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string TypeError { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlElement("error")]
    public List<Error> errors { get; private set; }
    public Errors()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Errors));

        using (Stream reader = new FileStream("ErrorString.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            errors = (List<Error>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Мой XML - документ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<errors>
    <error>
        <name>NOT_ENOUGH_SEARCH_LENGTH</name>
        <description>Require at least 3 characters</description>
    </error>
    <error>
        <name>INVALID_SEARCH</name>
        <description>The search is invalid</description>
    </error>
    <error>
        <name>SEARCH_NOT_SPECIFIED</name>
        <description>Empty search field</description>
    </error>
    <error>
        <name>INVALID_FIELDS</name>
        <description>Inputed filed isn't correct</description>
    </error>
    <error>
        <name>ACCOUNT_ID_NOT_SPECIFIED</name>
        <description>Application id haven't been provided</description>
    </error>
    <error>
        <name>METHOD_DISABLED</name>
        <description>Function in API was diasbled by Wargaming</description>
    </error>
    <error>
        <name>APPLICATION_IS_BLOCKED</name>
        <description>Your application ID have been banned by Wargaming</description>
    </error>
    <error>
        <name>INVALID_IP_ADDRESS</name>
        <description>IP address is not allow for server application</description>
    </error>
    <error>
        <name>SOURCE_NOT_AVAILABLE</name>
        <description>Data isn't available</description>
    </error>
</errors>
```

Данная ошибка у меня происходит при тестировании. При нормальной работе - не проверял, так как пишу библиотеку.
При дебаге теста, у меня почему - то после первого прочтения, дебаг кидает так, будто только-только вошел в конструктор и выбивает внутреннюю ошибку о том, что он не может открыть файл.

Comment: Вы попробуйте свой класс сериализовать и поглядеть разницу между вашим xml и результатом сериализации.

Comment: Это случаем не для Wargaming PAPI? Я из Wargaming. Здесь кстати не все ошибки, у отдельных методов есть свои типы ошибок. И почему XML? Вроде вы работаете с JSON API, значит у вас есть соответствующий сериализатор в приложении. Сериализуйте список ошибок в JSON, с ним намного удобнее работать. У вас еще много опечаток в текстах, если вам нужны тексты на английском, зайдите в европейский кабинет разработчика, возьмите там готовые английские тексты ошибок.

Comment: Пардон, не надо в европейский кабинет идти, в русском кабинете в футере есть переключалка `RUS | ENG`

Comment: @aepot все верно, я делаю обертку для WargamingAPI. Почему не с JSON? Сглупил, возможно, я хотел убрать лишние данные, которые приходят с JSON ответом. Да, ошибок много, когда начну работать над WoWs, буду исправлять оишбки.

Comment: Пишите мне в личку на форуме, если что - Midnight, помогу, чем смогу с C# и PAPI. Я как раз в Лесте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот полностью рабочий пример десериализации для вашего XML-файла.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\Temp\Errors.xml";
    Errors errors;
    
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Errors));

    using (Stream reader = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        errors = (Errors)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}

[XmlRoot("errors")]
public class Errors
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "error")]
    public List<Error> errors { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("error")]
public class Error
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string TypeError { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Результат**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]